# Return all text within links from a specific div with JSoup

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to parse through a list of links in a specific div. I can get the links just fine using the `#div>a` cssQuery syntax. But I can't get the text from inside:

```
private static Elements getLinkList(String URL) throws IOException {
 /* Download HTML page */
 URL website = new URL(URL);
 ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(HTML_DOC);
 fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

 /* Collect list of links */
 File input = new File(HTML_DOC);
 Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", URL);

 return document.select("#div>a");
}
```

I'm trying to get the text from inside the  tags but it's blank.

```
<div id="div">
    <a href="http://www.sample.com/doc.doc" target="_blank">Installation guideline - Citrix XenApp 7.6 for PAS-X.doc<br></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer requires no code changes to the code I posted in my OP:

```
private static Elements getLinkList(String URL) throws IOException {
 /* Download HTML page */
 URL website = new URL(URL);
 ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(HTML_DOC);
 fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

 /* Collect list of links */
 File input = new File(HTML_DOC);
 Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", URL);

 return document.select("#div>a");
}
```

But when processing the data, retrieve the text from the link `Element` itself i.e. `String titleText = link.text()`, and for completion:

```
Elements links = getLinkList(URL); // Retrieve list of Elements from above method

for (Element link: links) {
 String linkText = link.toString();
 String titleText = link.text();
 String formattedLink = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringBetween(linkText, "<a href=\"", "\"");

 System.out.println(titleText);
 System.out.println(formattedLink);
}
```